# How to get java.io.File from Apache's UploadedFile class?

Tags: java, apache, file, file-upload

How do I convert an uploaded file from apache's `UploadedFile` class to a `java.io.File` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation ([`UploadedFile`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/custom/fileupload/UploadedFile.html) and [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)) for both classes, here's one solution.

Since you can access the `InputStream` of the `UploadedFile`, you can read in  the data of the uploaded file and write it to a temporary location or another location that your application can manage.

```
// assume that you have the UploadedFile object named uploadedFile
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(uploadedFile.getInputStream());
int partition = 1024;
int length = 0;
int position = 0;
char[] buffer = new char[partition];
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.tmp");
do{
    length = reader.read(buffer, position, partition)
    fstream.write(buffer, position, length);
}while(length > 0);
File file = new File("out.tmp");
```

Comment: error shown in the following line- **while(length = reader.read(buffer, position, partition))** Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

Comment: Tried this method but copied file was broken. System said "cannot open file".

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use apache commons [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) .

```
File destFile= new File("somefile.txt");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(uploadedFile.getInputStream(), destFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(uploadedFile.getInputstream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
File f = new File("file.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,false);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   fw.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
}
```

This code will return your uploaded file in txt file.