# Convert an UploadedFile into a File

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, javaw

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.2 and I should store a file on filesystem.
Now, I know that the class FileUploaded creates a temp file so I would convert it into a real file using java.io.File.

Here it is my code:

```
String fileName = "D:/upload/file.zip"; //--- this is an example, in my real code it is dynamic
UploadedFile uploadedFile;

//--- getters and setters
InputStream in = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

The problem is that into the folder the application create a .tmp file but after it isn't "convert" to the file that I want!
The log returns:

```
[#|2012-04-20T16:30:13.109+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=114;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\upload\file.zip (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at it.cyborg.cdg.jsfClasses.AbstractController.copyFile(AbstractController.java:240)
    at it.cyborg.cdg.jsfClasses.ProgettiController.create(ProgettiController.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at it.cyborg.cdg.logic.RolesFilter.doFilter(RolesFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

I tried also this solution:

[How to get java.io.File from Apache's UploadedFile class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469987/how-to-get-java-io-file-from-apaches-uploadedfile-class)

But I received the same error.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I met the similar problem before, it is very simple, You just need to create a new File for it. But firstly, you should confirm the path you want to write is available.
Here is the sample code

```
//This is used for new file creation.
File f = new File(ParentPath, FileName);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Or you can just use java.nio.Files for it.

```
Files.newOutputStream(path, options);
```

Please check javadoc for it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I should create manually the path also for the solution of my problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
            moveFile(file.getInputstream(), file.getFileName());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);
        }


private Boolean moveFile(InputStream inputStream, String name) {

    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    String path = "/Users/barry/Desktop/";
    Boolean flag = false;
    try {

        outputStream
                = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + name));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
        flag = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       flag = false;
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                // outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the primefaces example.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() throws IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

        System.out.println("Uploaded file now: " + file.getFileName());

        String name = file.getFileName();

        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputstream();
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String path = "/Users/daryl/Desktop/";

        File file = new File(path + name);

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this code for converting an UploadedFile into a java File.

```
File f = new File(uploadedFile.getFileName());
```

Comment: Well no, this methods creates an empty file with the uploaded filename